# Why is the length byte of this ATS so large?

Tags: nfc, rfid, mifare, contactless-smartcard, lib-nfc

Testing with a DESFire, I picked up the following ATS: `0x75  0x77  0x81  0x02  0x80`.

From what I can tell, [ISO/IEC 14443-4](http://www.emutag.com/iso/14443-4.pdf) says that the first byte should be the "length byte" and should indicate the total number of bytes sent as part of the ATS. Why, then, is the first byte `0x75`? If you ignore the first nibble, the value is correct, but is there any reason I should actually have to do that, or is there no relation between this byte and the length value?

Note: The ATS was obtained via libnfc through `nfc_initiator_select_passive_target`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ATS is perfectly fine. libnfc does not include the length byte in the value stored in `nt.nti.nai.abtAts`. Instead, the length of the ATS is stored in `nt.nti.nai.szAtsLen`. Consequently, the first byte is not the length byte but the format byte. It indicates that TA(1), TB(1), and TC(1) are present (Y(1) = 7h), and that the FSC is 64 bytes (FSCI = 5h). The remaining bytes then decode as:

- TA(1) = 77h: all three divisors supported for both directions
- TB(1) = 81h: FWT = 256 * 16 / f_c * 2^8 = 77 ms, SFGT = 256 * 16 / f_c * 2^1 = 600 us
- TC(1) = 02h: CID supported, NAD not supported
- Historical bytes: 80h